# android, how to monitering to the webview content size change without using javascript

Tags: android-webview

Having webview and need to reposition some overlay when the content in the webview changes.

one way is to listen "resize" in the loaded html,

```
    function onWindowResize(){
        // notify native side
        android.onWebPageStateChange('onWindowResize', data)
    }

    window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize);
```

and in webview's @JavascriptInterface function `onWebPageStateChange` 
it should know the webview content size changed.

However if the javascript is not an option (for any reason), is there a equivalent event in webview itself so that it could capture the webview content size change?

Answer (score 0):

seems this works without requiring javascript pre-exist within the html, although the first call may throw a exception that the call is undefined yet. any other alternative?

```
    private fun addingHtmlWindowSizeChangeListener() {
        val strJs = "window.addEventListener(\"resize\", \n" +
            "function onWindowResize(){\n" +
            "    try {\n" +

            "        console.log('+++ js +++ onWindowResize() ')\n" +

            "        if (typeof javascript_obj !== \"undefined\") {\n" +
            "            javascript_obj.onWebPageStateChange('onWindowResize', 'onWindowResize')\n" +
            "        }\n" +
            "    } catch (e) {\n" +
            "        console.log('+++ !!! exception at onWindowResize()s. error: '+e)\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "});\n"

        wvContent?.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { $strJs })();",
            null)
        wvContent?.evaluateJavascript(
            "(function() { try {onWindowResize();} catch (e) { console.log('+++ !!! exception at calling onWindowResize()s. error: '+e) } })();",
            null)
    }
```